# How to use Jetpack View Binding for Abstract Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

I have two fragments which have a lot in common. Therefore, I have an abstract fragment with an "abstract" layout file for this, which is included in the other two layout files.

However, I am not sure, how to use Jetpack View Binding for the abstract fragment, because I don't know which layout file is used.

---

Here a simplified example of my problem:

Abstract fragment (ExampleAbstractFragment.kt):

```
abstract class ExampleAbstractFragment : Fragment() {
    
    override fun doSomething() {
        val abstractTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.abstract_text_view)
        // ^^ How to get this with View Binding
        val abstractButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.abstract_button)
        // ^^ How to get this with View Binding
    }
}
```

Layout file of abstract fragment (fragment_example_abstract.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/abstract_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/abstract_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

--

First fragment (ExampleFragmentA.kt):

```
class ExampleFragmentA : ExampleAbstractFragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentAExampleBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentAExampleBinding?.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
         super.onDestroyView()
         _binding = null
    }

    override fun doSomething() {
        val textView = binding.fragmentAExampleTextView
        val button = binding.fragmentAExampleButton
    }
}
```

Layout file of first fragment (fragment_a_example.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_a_example_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/fragment_example_abstract"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fragment_a_example_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

--

Second fragment (ExampleFragmentB.kt):

```
class ExampleFragmentB : ExampleAbstractFragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentBExampleBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentBExampleBinding?.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
         super.onDestroyView()
         _binding = null
    }

    override fun doSomething() {
        val editText = binding.fragmentBExampleEditText
        val imageView = binding.fragmentBExampleImageView
    }
}
```

Layout file of second fragment (fragment_b_example.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fragment_b_example_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/fragment_example_abstract"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_b_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I have a similar situation...

Comment: @JaromírMalenko: It is not an ideal solution, but I solved it in the following way:
In the abstract fragment I have an abstract function getAbstractBinding() which will be implemented by the first and second fragment and returns the binding of the abstract layout. This function will be used in the abstract fragment to get the binding.
I hope, this is clear for your. Otherwise I can give you an example code.

Comment: That's clear. Thank you. Your soulution seems right (and better than mine :-) ).
I don't have so clear hierarvhy, but a normal layout and then a debug layout that includes the normal layout and TextView for logging. I'm using both bindings (in if statements) to do the layout by `setContentView()`, but use class fields to reference the views (e.g.: `canvas = binding.includeDrawing.canvas` ).